# Database query to display a message when there are no results

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I've created a nice application using eclipse that is something like a dictionary app - basically a list of terms that are searchable. I would like to create a new activity when the user searches for a term that is not present. At the moment, the list view is blank when this happens and I don't think this is very helpful so I would at least like to have a popup or something that says "no such term" or "please submit this new term" or something rather than blankness.

Every time I search for an answer to this challenge, I am bombarded with questions related to database problems and the like.

Can I add a condition to the code below when there is no/null/zero results found?

```
public void search(View view) { 
  cursor = db.rawQuery(
      "SELECT _id, term, definition FROM term WHERE term LIKE ?", 
      new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});

  adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
      this, 
      R.layout.term_list_layout, 
      cursor, 
      new String[] {"term", "definition"}, 
      new int[] {R.id.term, R.id.definition});

  setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `setEmptyView()` for the listview with whatever you want to show when there are no results

**Edit**

check the cursor like this

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    //cursor is no empty, set up list
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
  this, 
  R.layout.term_list_layout, 
  cursor, 
  new String[] {"term", "definition"}, 
  new int[] {R.id.term, R.id.definition});

  setListAdapter(adapter);
}else{
    //cursor is empty start new activity
}
```

Comment: Ok. This might be a good solution. But I would like to take it a step further and start an activity when the no results condition occurs. I was hoping there was some way to do a if results = false -> start activity...

Comment: then just check and see if your cursor is empty then before doing anything. If its empty start a new activity if not then show your list

Comment: Thanks so much. you pointed me in the right direction. Here is my working solution:

if(cursor.getCount() == 0)

*Now to figure out how to grab that searched term and use it in the new activity...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make use of the "Empty" view for your listview. This view will be displayed whenever the listview contains no entries.

```
mMyListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyView));
```

You can also set the view in XML by specifying the correct ID which is `@android:id/empty`

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="List is empty"
       android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Yes, you have the understanding of my question pretty close. This might be a good solution. But I would like to take it a step further and start an activity when the no results condition occurs. I was hoping there was some way to do a statement like; if results = false -> start activity...

Comment: Check your adapter after populating it. If it contains results then start your new activity